# Problem with \renewcommand in LaTeX

Tags: formatting, environments

Please consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany]{book}

\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
   paperwidth=216mm, paperheight=303mm,
   left=23mm,  %% or inner=23mm
   right=18mm, %% or outer=18mm
   top=23mm, bottom=23mm,
   headheight=\baselineskip,
   headsep=7mm,
   footskip=7mm
}


%% Command to hold chapter illustration image
\newcommand\chapterillustration{}

%% Define how the chapter title is printed
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0pt}{
%% Background image at top of page
\ThisULCornerWallPaper{1}{\chapterillustration}
%% Draw a semi-transparent rectangle across the top
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
  \fill[LightSalmon1,opacity=.7]
  (current page.north west) rectangle 
  ([yshift=-3cm] current page.north east);
  %% Check if on an odd or even page
  \checkoddpage\strictpagecheck
  %% On odd pages, "logo" image at lower right
  %% corner; Chapter number printed near spine
  %% edge (near the left); chapter title printed
  %% near outer edge (near the right).
  \ifoddpage{
    \ThisLRCornerWallPaper{.35}{image3}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,
      xshift=20mm,yshift=-30mm,
      font=\sffamily\bfseries\huge] 
      at (current page.north west) 
      {\chaptername\ \thechapter};
    \node[fill=Sienna!80!black,text=white,
      font=\Huge\bfseries, 
      inner ysep=12pt, inner xsep=20pt,
      rounded rectangle,anchor=east, 
      xshift=-20mm,yshift=-30mm] 
      at (current page.north east) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  %% On even pages, "logo" image at lower left
  %% corner; Chapter number printed near outer
  %% edge (near the right); chapter title printed
  %% near spine edge (near the left).
  \else {
    \ThisLLCornerWallPaper{.35}{image3}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,
      xshift=-20mm,yshift=-30mm,
      font=\sffamily\bfseries\huge] 
      at (current page.north east)
      {\chaptername\ \thechapter};
    \node[fill=Sienna!80!black,text=white,
      font=\Huge\bfseries,
      inner sep=12pt, inner xsep=20pt,
      rounded rectangle,anchor=west,
      xshift=20mm,yshift=-30mm] 
      at ( current page.north west) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \fi
}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{135mm}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand\chapterillustration{image1}
\chapter{First Chapter}

\renewcommand\chapterillustration{image2}
\chapter{Second Chapter}

\end{document}
```

Problem:
On compiling with pdflatex, the output PDF contains "image2" only - for both chapter headings.

i.e. The code section:

```
\renewcommand\chapterillustration{image1}
\chapter{First Chapter}

\renewcommand\chapterillustration{image2}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
```

is producing "image2" for both the Chapters.

Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by the asynchronous behaviour of TeX: Your images are placed when pages are built, which happens well after typesetting. If you insert a `\newpage` in front of `\renewcommand\chapterillustration{image2}`, the problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I can't insert blank new pages in the book, after every Chapter. Can't we have some another solution for this?

Comment: I haven't studied your layout in detail, but I had assumed that, when you make chapter illustrations part of the page layout, that you do want each chapter to start on a new page? If this is not so, then I am confused as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your point. Your fix is fine.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a uglier solution but you get rid of the `\newpage`:

Change the following lines in your preamble

```
%% Command to hold chapter illustration image
\newcommand{\chapterillustration}[1]{%
\expandafter\newcommand\csname chillu\roman{chapter}\endcsname{#1}}

%% Define how the chapter title is printed
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0pt}{
%% Background image at top of page
\ThisULCornerWallPaper{1}{\csname chillu\roman{chapter}\endcsname}
```

and use it like this in your document:

```
\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapterillustration{image1}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\chapterillustration{image2}
```

Comment: If you use \roman instead of \alph you won't run out of numbers ;-)

Comment: @StephanLehmke Good point. I wasn't aware that the romans foresightedly designed their numeral system compatible with the name conventions of TeX macros.

Comment: leads to compilation error:File `\chillui .mps' not found

Comment: Did you take into account that you have to switch the order of `\chapter` and `\chapterillustration` in your original code? When I use `\chapterillustration` before `\chapter` I get the same error.

Comment: @periswon:Thanks for your kind help. I want to share this will all of you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491904/latex-how-to-remove-blank-pages-coming-between-two-chapters-in-appendix. Setting: \documentclass[oneside]{book} removes ALL the Blank Pages from the Book :)